# Creating arc segment between two points with common field using Python?

Tags: python

[image]

I need to create Arc Segments between multiple points with like data using half the distance between the two like points as the radius of the arc segment.

I would prefer to use python to accomplish this.

Comment: This is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436421/drawing-a-circular-arc-using-arcpy

Comment: Try reading [this thread](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15181/how-to-create-arcs-between-two-points-in-python).

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5204/curved-point-to-point-route-maps

Comment: Your graphic example looks rather like a contour interpolation problem! Is that the intention? Also, why do you wish the curvature to be a function of the separation of the points?