# Effectively displaying a large amount of data on Google Maps APi

Tags: web-mapping, web-service, optimization

I have about 20 layers that I'd like to put on a Google maps API. I assume I'll need some form of a tile cache server and perhaps under mapserver or geoserver. These layers amount to about 400mb so the option of using static maps using kml/kmz is not an option. The data exists on two geodatabases, ESRI and PostGIS.

Can you provide insights on publishing large amounts of data to google maps api? especially in a way that allows users to easily do queries,load and unload layers at a relatively acceptable speed? Are there any good reads that improve the understanding of the issues and challenges?

Answer (score 4):

GeoServer and GeoWebCache will serve your maps and OpenLayers will put Google or other basemaps underneath them.

Answer (score 4):

You might take a look at the new Google Fusion Tables.  I personally haven't worked with it much yet and don't know if it works well with amount of data you have but storing data on Google large server base might be a good thing.  Here are a couple pf links to some blogs and the Fusion Tables.

Fusion Tables:
http://www.google.com/fusiontables/Home

Google Developer Blog:
http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/11/search-your-geo-data-using-spatial.html

Safe Software:
http://blog.safe.com/2010/12/google-evolves-spatial-offerings-with-fusion-tables/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ItsAllAboutData+%28It%27s+All+About+Data%29&utm_content=Google+Reader

Comment: I've tried fusion tables, but the issue seems that you have to upload your data to their servers, and some of this data, we can only display, but not share

Comment: After doing a little more reading I don't think it would work for you anyway, there is a 100 MB limit for KML.

Comment: but you can add multiple kmls i think

Answer (score 2):

**SuperOverlay**
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/regions.html
(scroll to the bottom)

But you will need to use the EARTH API for this to work on Google Maps API (Earth Mode)

Note: using it on standard Google Map tile modes will not work (KML is limited)

Answer (score 2):

I heard mention of this some time ago. I havent't had a chance to try it myself. It is under BSD license.
[TileCacheServer](http://tilecache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

It is often useless to try to display so large amounts of data, because humans have limited capacities to read information (see [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/examples-of-badly-designed-maps/3132#3132)). Even if we had no network constraints to diffuse and display big datasets, we would have to face this readability constraint.

If a dataset is too large to be diffused and displayed, it means it has to be simplified according to the visualization scale. A solution may be to enrich your dataset into a multi-scale dataset using generalisation techniques and use a 'scale aware' web visualisation client.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I intend to only display minimal data through smart queries based on the location of a user place marker. or user inputed queries.

Comment: Comparable topic: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/8876/162