# Maximum number of point features in an OpenLayers vector layer

Tags: openlayers, web-mapping

In your experience, how many point features can be added to an OpenLayers vector layer (new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Point Layer")) before it goes unusably slow?

My use case is to display points from a database table. The user can decide which time frame to visualize. Therefore the result can be from very few to potentially 100,000s of points. I'd like to introduce a reasonable limit and warn the user if his query would return more features.

Comment: Is there a standard browser being used? The limit will likely be different depending on which browser you're using.

Comment: Mostly Firefox. It doesn't have to work in old IEs.

Comment: Rather than warn a user you could switch from requesting vector data to returning the points as a WMS / image.

Comment: @geographika: Usually I'd do that. But the user also gets to decide which database to connect to. I'd have to know all possible databases and have them available through a WMS. They don't even have PostGIS installed, i just fetch lat/lon columns.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I don't have a definitive answer for you but you I put together a page where you can play around with different numbers of points on an OL map:   http://derekswingley.com/lab/olpts/

Comment: You're welcome! I was curious too...

Comment: Derek there should be 'Great Answer with practical example' badge for that. Good to see the differences in speed overlying pointss.

Comment: Thanks, Mapperz! Guess I'll just have to settle for upvotes :)

Comment: Very interesting! It makes me think to the geoipsum. Alternatively, it can be use as well to test performance : http://craigmmills.com/geoipsum (I don't know if there is a polygon number limit)

Comment: The url doesn't work anymore :( do you have a workaround? I'm interested in the difference between feature in svg/canva or png . I'm actually working on an map with a lot of features and I could say that png is better for large number of features (> 1000)

Comment: @So4ne that google app engine site died at some point, the same (nearly 5 year old) code is here:  http://derekswingley.com/lab/olpts/

Comment: @DerekSwingley Nice that's exactly what I want :)

Comment: @DerekSwingley New link with code also does not work now. Do you have some actual link?

Comment: @nospor fallout from switching to https, updated and the site is back.

Comment: hope you dont mind my editing your answer, but it seemed unnecessary t leave the broken link and the working one, because some people, myself included, tend to click on the link BEFORE reading the rest of the answer.  TKS for a great answer (I like your randomizer, mind if I play around with it?). UPVOTED : )

Comment: @DerekSwingley I've made updated samples based on your idea using Leaflet, MapboxGL JS & OpenLayers 4 https://medium.com/@ThomasG77/rendering-points-in-web-mapping-the-match-f0d8b30664fb I put credits for your sample

Comment: @ThomasG77 nice, thanks for the credit and applying the same idea to more modern/relevant frameworks

Answer (score 5):

If the display goes slow because of the too high feature number, it means that the data to display are not suitable for the zoom level. Usually, when the features density goes too high, the display can not be readable anymore (see [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/examples-of-badly-designed-maps/3132#3132)). Even if there was no processing limit and all the display devices were able to display 1000000000000 features in 0.001s on a small screen, the visualisation would remain impossible.

The Töpfer's radix law states that feature density should remain under a constant threshold whatever the zoom level. A way to solve this issue and adapt the data to the visualisation scale is to transform it using [generalisation operations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/440/162) like [this one](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/) or [this other one](http://v2.maptimize.com/).

Comment: On the same topic: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/4096/162

Comment: Very true. And regarding Openlayers, it uses *cluster strategy* to handle that. See example : http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster.html

Comment: For my current application, I simply connected the (GPS) points to lines (tracks). That already improves rendering time considerably.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is not possible to give solid answer for this question. Rendering point/polygons fully depend on browser and hardware (CPU & memory) not with OpenLayers. I had problem with Openlayers and IE6 for one of the Lake (Polygon) rendering. but, it loaded nicely in Firefox. And best option would be monitor the memory and CPU usage with Chrome or some tools would be better.

Answer (score 2):

In OpenLayers 6, there is a WebGL point renderer which should allow you to render 100s of thousands of features, with time based filtering. You May want to check out the latest version of the official workshop at https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/webgl/.

With OpenLayers 2, which I really don’t recommend to use any more, the maximum for acceptable frame rate will be a few hundred features only.

Answer (score 1):

As others, I have no answer regarding that question, but applying a [BBox strategy](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.7/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/BBOX-js.html) could help you keeping just the needed data since it displays only features located within the given bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on a similar use case, not sure whether it will suit the above mentioned needs but [`Clustering`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Cluster-Cluster.html) in OL 5 is what I adopted.

Clustering as the words suggests takes a group of points and merge them togther in a single point e.g. you have 100 points in particular city all the points will be visible as one point from a zoom of let's say `4` but as individual points from a zoom of let's  say `10` so what you can do is when the zoom is `4` you can join those points as one, what this does it helps reducing the number of points to be rendered in a particular area.

In other words, let's say you have 10,000 points to be rendered on the map and they are pretty close to each other, so you can make clusters of them and reduce rendering and when the user zooms in you keep breaking the clusters. This will ensure that you have less rendering and better performance.

Satisfying performance. [Link to Clustering examples on Openlayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html)

Comment: Could you please add a short summary of the page linked? Links may break with time, leaving your answer useless as it is now.