# Openlayers Add features performance for 3000 lines

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, polyline-creation

We would like to implement the function of Addfeature in openlayers to draw lines and push them onto a vector layer, and overlay this layer onto open street map or google map. Those lines are draw dynamically based on the query results from the database.
The only concern so far is the performance issue since we are anticipating about 3000 lines per operation. Has anyone worked on this kind of project before? Do you think it is too heavy on the client side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely heavy on the client side. On average, how many vertices per features? You will definitely tax older browsers.

A little while back I put together [a simple app for an arbitrary number of points in an OpenLayers app](http://swingley.appspot.com/maps/olpts) as a response to a [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/8876/124). Might be helpful for you to gauge performance with large number of graphics.

Comment: link to arbitrary points app is no longer working