# JS/browser API library to show/interact with many markers with the best performance?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, performance

What's the best Javascript library that can show about 50000 (and more) clickable markers without resorting to things like clustering markers,etc? The markers are clickable and I want to associate them with some action.

The main issue is coping with browser performance, so I'm already only considering performance in Chrome and Firefox. Yes, I also understand browser performance is dependent on the PC performance but still, there are better and worse libraries.

I have experience with GMaps v3 but with so many markers it is very slow. Changing to GEarth plugin on the browser solves the problem. Currently I'm using OpenLayers serving from my GeoServer WMS.

I guess I need a JS lib like Openlayers tailored for very high performance, for example using WebGL to make use of the PC's GPU. I know openlayers v3 would have webgl but I really want to hear the feedback from experienced users for these kind of big data on a map.

Also it should be opensource and free to use and be able to connect to my WMS to serve the tiles, like openlayers does.

I also don't mind if it's not JS API but some plugin I have to install on my PC / browser, like GEarth, if that improves the performance radically.

Comment: 50000 markers? This is one of the times I am going to say: Why???

Comment: I have asked two relevant questions: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19117/openlayers-canvas-renderer-redraws-all-features-on-selecting-a-single-feature and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18572/openlayers-alternatives-supporting-more-client-side-features

Comment: also "tailored for very high performance" implies that you don't think OpenLayers is already written to be fast. Mapping APIs is a competitive field and everyone wants fast

Comment: Your motivation to display 50k points at once aside, there was a [Ten thousands points](http://dev.camptocamp.com/files/fredj/812/examples/ten-thousand-points.html) sample showcasing OL3 with WebGL. It does not work for me though, it might be outdated. But I believe a WebGL approach is your best bet at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

With a large number of points why do you not want to use clustering?

With that said, I use a MySQL database to load my markers.  Granted there are not 50K but using a MySQL DB is an easy way to manage a large number of markers.  [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) is a good tutorial in using MySQL/PHP is store and output markers onto Google Maps.

Comment: I guess the OP is more concerned with rendering performance on the front-end.

Comment: I think using PHP/MySQL would improve performance on the front end for 50K points.