# how do you sort points so that they are geographically near each other

Tags: google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One dimensional map of the world?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15528/one-dimensional-map-of-the-world)

I am trying to create a google map.  I am creating placemarkers using an external script in a kml file.

I'd like to sort the markers so that the ones which are geographically close are listed together.  e.g., Los Angeles and San Francisco should appear next to each other, while New York and New Jersey will be close to each other.

Is there any way to sort this list?  Should I be using the latitude/longitude?

Note: I am not asking how to visualize this on a map.

Comment: Basically the same as: [One dimensional map of the world?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15528/one-dimensional-map-of-the-world)