# How to Set Page Numbers with Strip Map Index Features Tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, data-driven-pages, strip-map

I have used the `Strip Map Index Features` tool to create an Index Layer for Data Driven Pages.  The problem is with the page numbering that the tool creates.  Some of the page numbers are in order, but others seem random.  Here is the tool as I ran it:

[image: Tool]

Here is the result I got:

[image: Result]

How can I modify the tool so that the page numbers are in some order?  My preferred order would be along individual polylines from West to East and North to South.

Comment: Are you asking about modifying the page numbers or modifying the tool so you can re-run it and get the results you desire?

Comment: I am asking about re-running the tool to produce the desired page numbers.  I could edit the polygon layer and type the desired page numbers in manually but I am looking to get around that if possible.

Comment: This post might be of assistance: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/60134/7424

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that network of lines, there's no way for ArcGIS to figure out which page you'd like to be "first". The strip map tool is meant to create a mapbook along one line feature, it doesn't do so well with more than one, especially if they crisscross each other like yours do.

However, it does look like it covered all of your lines with mapbook pages, and they're oriented more or less correctly. In your situation, I'd just edit the index layer and re-number the pages however you want them to be ordered. I would also remove some of the pages, when you have overlapping lines and you use the Strip Map tool, you can get unnecessary pages where your lines meet, because the tool is generating a complete map set for each line feature individually. Pages 24 and 48 in your screenshot, for example, seem to be redundant.

If you want to be able to generate the pages automatically, you will probably have better luck using the [Grid Index Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_grid_index_features/00s900000025000000/) tool instead.

Comment: What do you think the result would be if I merged all of the polyline features together into one feature before running the tool?  I don't have time to run it right now, but it would be interesting to see the result of that.

Comment: You could try that, you could also try selecting each "branch" of your set of lines separately and generating a strip map index for each individually, then combining them. You'd still need to manually edit the page numbers though.

Comment: I just had a chance to look this over.  Manually editing the page numbers seems to be the best solution. Thanks! @Dan