# How to present three spatial variables in one map?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, cartography, symbology, visualisation

I want to assign 3 category of variables in a single map.
In other words, I have to produce a cartographic visualization of the damage including a legend listing:

- damaged surface area in the residential areas (in km2),
- number of living units and number of people affected, and
- damage in terms of euroes.

I just can present two of them by "graduated colors" and "graduated symbols".
I cannot add third variable, in a meaningful way.

How I can present all the 3 variable in a same snapshot simultaneously?

Comment: Is your data points, polygons, or a raster? And you seem to have listed four things - item 2 has a couple of things...

Comment: You could try some of the solutions suggested in answers to [Effectively displaying demographic data on a printed map](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4568/effectively-displaying-demographic-data-on-a-printed-map) question.

Comment: Do you have a map layer for the damaged surface areas?  I would suggest that the map layer itself would display the damaged area.  That leaves the two remaining variables, which you can plot with the colors and symbols.

Comment: You can try using charts, [pie](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000016000000), [column](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000003000000) or [stacked](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000030000000)

Comment: Perhaps a 3D (perspective view) of the area, with a couple of columns or other icons)? It may be a problem depending on the "depth" of the view.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming polygon layer

1. Damage in euros: polygon outline thickness
2. surface damage in km2 polygon transparency
3. Number of units polygon color ramp or chloropleth symbology

Answer (score 0):

You want to represent four variables:

- damaged surface area in the residential areas [km2]
- number of living units affected
- number of people affected
- damage [euroes]

All these variables are **absolute** values.

Assuming you have polygon layer please take into account:

**Absolute** data should **not** be used in choropleth mapping. Do not use a color ramp to color the area (fill color) of a polygon. So do not do this if you want to show “number of people affected”: Color ramp: bright red to dark red

Instead of showing absolute values you should show **relative** values: You can divide the “number of people affected” by the “number of people living in this area”. ArcView is able to calculate this on-the-fly (layer properties dialog). Then you can use a color ramp to color the area (fill color) of a polygon.

If you want to show absoute values (“number of people affected”) you have to use dot distribution or proportional symbols.

I see no possibility to use charts. I.e. there is no sense to show the “number of people affected” and the “damage [euros]” together in one pie chart.

I think that it's too much to show all your 4 values in one map. Often it is better to make several maps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Synthetic Map (i'm not sure of the terminology so correct me please), [here an example this maps using 3 variables](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~whitede/attachments/mass.landcover.70s.jpg), or you can plot your data to identify the tending groups like [in this example](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~whitede/attachments/mass.landcover.scatter.jpg) , so you may reduce the complexity of your variables to a limited set of clusters.

source web page http://people.oregonstate.edu/~whitede/ternary.htm

Comment: I think you were trying to refer to `Relationship Map` definition. check these articles [How to Make a Relationship Map in ArcGIS Online](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/how-to-make-a-relationship-map-in-arcgis-online/) and [Sequential Sequential Color Schemes](http://www.personal.psu.edu/cab38/ColorSch/SchHTMLs/CBColorSeqSeq.html).