Rendering polygon by two variables in QGIS
I have a set of polygons with two variables "variable 1" which can take values A, B, C, D, and E and "variable 2" which can take values V, W, X, Y and Z.
I would want to render the polygon by the crosstabulation of these two variables. So the legend might look something like this:

I could do it by concatenating variable 1 and variable 2 and individually specifying the 25 colours, but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution already implemented in QGIS?

Have you seen this thread before: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315340/creating-bivariate-choropleth-map-a-k-a-relationship-map-in-qgis ?

Use a similar technique to that link, have the A-E layer coloured as per your palette, and above that the V-Z coloured grayscale, then set the blending mode so that V-Z modifies the base colour.

We can achieve this by combining Categorized symbols based on 'Variable 1' with color lightness based on  'Variable 2'.

Categorize symbols based on 'Variable 1'  as follows:

Then select each colour and apply an expression to each fill colour as follows. 'Variable 2' is used to adjust the lightness of the colour:


 CASE 
    WHEN  "Variable 2" = 'V' THEN lighter( @symbol_color, 125)
    WHEN  "Variable 2" = 'W' THEN lighter( @symbol_color, 150)
    WHEN  "Variable 2" = 'X' THEN lighter( @symbol_color, 175)
    WHEN  "Variable 2" = 'Y' THEN lighter( @symbol_color, 200)
    WHEN  "Variable 2" = 'Z' THEN lighter( @symbol_color, 225)
 END


Elegant. Just for further explanation. The values in the function set the translucent levels. That ranges from 0 to 255.

Thank you. I believe lighter() sets the brightness not the translucent level (transparency).
https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-color-lighter

Ha! My mistake. I thought this was setting the A value for RGBA.
