# Maps with charts of representative symbols

Tags: symbology, representation, chart

How would the type of map symbology illustrated here be typically described?

[image]

Specifically where symbology is used to represent arbitrary quantities of phenomena, and these being charted together for a particular zone.  I'm looking for good examples of this type of approach (to compare favourably to the seeming preference these days that many people have for embedding pie charts inside polygons), but am not sure if there is a standardised term.  Can anyone clarify?

I seem to remember a pretty good example of this approach focussed on the US western coast, but I forget the author and specific context..

Comment: I would call them glyphs, but I'm not sure if that is a standardized terminology. See http://www.citeulike.org/user/apwheele/article/12238640, and http://www.citeulike.org/user/apwheele/article/11627768 for examples. A variety of examples can be found in MacEachren's *How Maps Work*, and some notable ones are from the work of Dan Carr and William Cleveland (and pie charts from Minard!) It is similar to the ISOTYPE like graphing symbols as well.

Comment: These symbols are used to represent arbitrary *quantities,* not just "discrete numbers of phenomena." Like most symbols used in cartography, they have been binned into discrete classes, but that does not change the nature of the variable being represented.

Comment: I agree 'arbitrary' is probably clearer than 'discrete'

Answer (score 6):

I would call them glyphs although I'm skeptical it is such an established adjective that it will be immediate to many audiences. Vasan et al. (2013) is a great review of different types of glyphs used in the literature (plus an experimental study for the differences between bricks like you show and clustered bars, pies, and sticks). The image below is from the cited paper and shows the different experimental stimulus:

[image]

Other ones I am familiar with are Chernoff faces and population pyramids (Dorling, 2012), filled rectangles to replace univariate choropleth maps (Cleveland & McGill 1984), star plots (Friendly, 2007; Wickham et al. 2012) and more complicated stick glyph variants (Maddox et al. 2013). Below is an example of Chernoff faces taken from Dorling (2012) (of course positioned according to a circular Dorling cartogram - I'm reading the Dorling book now and it has a ton of different types of glyphs I haven't seen elsewhere).

[image: Dorling Chernoff Faces]
<sub>(source: [dannydorling.org](http://www.dannydorling.org/books/visualisation/Graphics/Pages/Figures_files/Media/Figure%208.10/Figure%208.10.jpg?disposition=download))</sub>

Some notes on their use:

- Irregularly spaced data are typically more difficult to visualize and have problems of glyphs overlapping and being occluded (Wickham et al. 2012).
- Glyphs tend to generate extremely complicated maps. Because of this, it is often more effective use of space to make several small multiple maps as oppossed to one map will all of the information superimposed. See [Effectively displaying demographic data on a printed map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/4568/751) for related discussion.

---

## References

- Cleveland, William & Robert McGill. 1984. Graphical perception: Theory, experimentation, and application to the development of graphical methods. [*Journal of the American Statistical Association 79*(387):531-554](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2288400). [PDF Here](https://secure.cs.uvic.ca/twiki/pub/Research/Chisel/ComputationalAestheticsProject/cleveland.pdf).
- Dorling, Danny. 2012. *The visualisation of spatial social structure*. Wiley. [Original Dissertation Here Here](http://www.dannydorling.org/wp-content/files/dannydorling_publication_id2980.pdf). Images [Here](http://www.dannydorling.org/books/visualisation/Homepage.html).
- Friendly, Michael. 2007. A.M. Guerry's moral statistics of France: Challenges for multivariable spatial analysis. [*Statistical Science 22*(3):368-399](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/07-sts241). PDF Available from publisher.
- Maddox C., J. Corcoran & Y. Liu. 2013. Mapping spatial flows over time: A case study of using journey-to-work data. [*Journal of Spatial Science 58*(1):147-159](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/14498596.2012.759089).
- Vasa, Choengsa-ard, Nitin Tripathi & Paul Janecek. 2013. Effective graphic features for multivariate symbol mapping. [*The Cartographic Journal 50*(1):66-81](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/maney/caj/2013/00000050/00000001/art00007).
- Wickham, Hadley, Heike Hofmann, Charlotte Wickham & Dianne Cook. 2012. Glyph-maps for visually exploring temporal patterns in climate data and models. [*Environmetrics 23*(5):382-393](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/env.2152). [Pre-print PDF](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/glyph-maps.pdf).

Comment: +1 A practical comparative analysis of glyphs (on a regular grid) appears among the answers at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23895.  They demonstrate that glyphs do not necessarily generate complicated maps: indeed, their salient property is due to the capacity of our native visual processing system instantly and easily to identify spatial patterns within a huge collection of (simple) glyphs. For this to work well, each glyph must be stripped of all non-informational elements: the illustration in the present question is a good example.

Comment: Useful stuff Andy thanks (and to @farhat-abbas). I appreciate the value of a tried and tested bar chart (74.a) for conveying absolute and relative data.  Here however I'm specifically interested in the use of charted symbols to represent unit quantities of phenomena.

Comment: @whuber vector flow maps are great examples. Dorling has another that is one of the nicest examples of social science data I have seen [here](http://www.dannydorling.org/books/visualisation/Graphics/Pages/Figures_files/Media/Figure%205.20/Figure%205.20.jpg?disposition=download) (although IMO he could make the arrow heads smaller). The arrows point to changes in the ternary diagram of election results in Britain's three party system. Social science data are rarely so kind, and they are much more difficult to parse when the arrows aren't laid on on a regular grid and the surface isn't as smooth.

Comment: Although that might just suggest for such diagrams to be successful they should be smoothed (and placed on a regular grid) to begin with. @geotheory I have no idea what `use of charted symbols to represent unit quantities of phenomena` means - is there some confusion with my answer or another question you have?

Comment: If there is any confusion over the description I hope my example graphic explains what I mean.

Comment: @geotheory - you asked what the terminology would typically be described and I answered glyphs. I then gave a variety of different examples of glyphs, a bunch of citations and some general discussion of when they are most useful. What other information are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I've seen that particular statistical graphic called a [waffle chart](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/17842/1036) - and the point is loosely based on the ISOTYPE like diagrams of counting objects. Such glyphs are not regular enough to likely have any type of standardized terminology I imagine though.

Comment: @geothery did you read my answer - the terminology `glyphs` are specifically mentioned in Vasan et al. (2013); Wickham et al. (2012); Dorling (2012); Friendly (2007). When I say I doubt it is standardized terminology I am saying I doubt non-geographers would recognize the term. I stated in the second sentence of my answer `Vasan et al. (2013) is a great review of different types of glyphs`.

Comment: When working on visualization research in 1989 I came across a group in a New England university doing innovative work with symbols they specifically called "glyphs": these were the articulated stick figures akin to those in panel (c) of your first illustration, but they could have richer structures--more arms, more articulations on each arm, varying angles, and varying segment lengths. They work collectively to create impressions akin to vector flow fields and Chernoff face fields. I apologize for forgetting the name of the group or their institution.

Comment: @whuber - I've seen Dan Carr use the stick figures most often I believe, e.g. http://mason.gmu.edu/~dcarr/lib/v9n2.pdf and http://goo.gl/JoMwve. I think I remember seeing a similar example to what you describe in the Slocum textbook, the glyph field was so dense it created the impression of an actual surface. If I wanted to dig up more references I would go back to Slocum and *How Maps Work* - I hope this is a sufficient start for whomever though!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but checkout http://dataveyes.com/blog/rennes/index-en.html it may help you to build similar visualization.

http://www.inquiron.com